# Give an example which shows that a function $f$ need not be complex differentiable at $z_0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

> If we have a analytic map $f: D(0,1) \to \Bbb C$ on the whole disc $D(0,1)$, then prove that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold on all points of $D(0,1)$. Furthermore suppose that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold on $z_0 \in D(0,1)$. Give an example which shows that a function $f$ need not be complex differentiable at $z_0$.

For the first question, let $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, then $$f’(x+iy) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y) + i \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y) $$ and $$f’(x+iy) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x,y) -i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)$$ and putting these together gives the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

For the second part I cannot come up with an example. What kind of maps should I be consider in order for them to be analytic at a point, but not  complex differentiable?

Comment: at a point?  I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I think the second part is meant to be read separately, as in, the analyticity condition from before is dropped. Otherwise there is no such function, because analyticity implies complex differentiability.

Comment: Yes the second part is seperate. It’s perhaps not quite clear from the formulation.

Comment: There is a classic example $f(z)=e^{-1/z^4}, z \ne 0, f(0)=0$ where $f$ is not continuous hence not differentiable at zero, but the partial derivatives exist (actually in any order) and satisfy C-R as they are all zero

Comment: The above is the obvious generalization of the classic $C^{\infty}$ but not analytic function on the reals but we use power four to get same behavior for $iy$ too